# How to navigate from one controller to another View Controller programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "GMNewPostControllerSegueIdentifier"
{
   let svc = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
   let vc: GMNewPostController = svc?.topViewController as! GMNewPostController
 }
}
    
@IBAction func newPostButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "GMNewPostController", sender: self)
}
```

I don't like to drag and drop from my storyboard because I have a table view in vc2.

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder at all? Or do the view controllers not even appear on storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to do this:

> Using Push:

```
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewStoryID")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

You have to set ViewController ID in storyBoard like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you added navigation controller in the root view controller?

Comment: Please check my updated Image to set navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

[Check below image , storyboard should like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcSuY.png)

And take a reference Action for button and write like this

[For button Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQU5U.png)

Comment: Delete button and take newly and then try

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the Image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/932EZ.png)

look at the picture, I want to navigate from green btn to the viewcontroller ..?

Comment: @ishank-dubey This is not an answer. Please do not edit off-topic posts. Instead, flag as "very low quality" or "not an answer", and downvote and vote to delete if you can. Thanks.